# Which data model strategy to use for a relatively simple app?

Tags: iphone

For a relatively simple app that manipulates objects that store a date/time and some other values? Should I use property lists? archiving? or sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

Plists are the simplest way to do save data.  Use the built in saving methods in the collection classes (NSarray, NSDict, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).